# Тень для формы без бордеров

Tags: c#

Всем привет, как сделать тень для формы c свойством FormBorderStyle = none?

- такой ([Add Drop Shadow to Borderless Form](http://www.csharp411.com/add-drop-shadow-to-borderless-form/)) вариант не подходит, так как нужна полноценная тень, как у окон windows, т.е. со всех сторон.
- вариант с отрисовкой полупрозрачной формы "под" основной, тоже не подходит, так как тень получается "топорной", как обычный прямоугольник, с четкими границами.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь css-свойством [box-shadow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow).

Ещё это обсуждается [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144312/winforms-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-formborderstyle-none-windowsforms-c).