# Полноценная тень для формы без бордеров

Tags: c#, winforms

Проект WindowsForms;
Язык C#;

Возникла необходимость сделать тень для формы (со свойством `FormBorderStyle=none`), похожую на стандартную тень окон windows:

[image]

- вариант "нарисовать png-картинку с тенью, а фон формы сделать прозрачным" дал вот такой результат:

[image]

- вариант "нарисовать полупрозрачную форму сзади" тоже не подходит, потому-что выглядит убого:

[image]

Есть варианты решения задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь css-свойством [box-shadow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow).

Comment: Уважаемый, Вы упоролись?

Comment: вообще-то это C#(WindowsForms), причем тут css-ный box-shadow?

Comment: вообще-то изначально вместо изображений в вопросе была html-разметка, я и подумал что автор наверное имел ввиду webforms. сейчас согласен - box-shadow не поможет

Comment: это было долго... муторно... но я не сдался и решил, этот вопрос -_-

но у меня нет 50 очков, чтоб ответить на свой вопрос(

так, что кому интересно, смотрите здесь http://forum.codenet.ru/q71753